# Why matcher loops forever when using find() and "" as a pattern?

Tags: java, regex, loops, match

When given empty string as a pattern the following code loops forever. Why this code loops forever? Did I misuse find(int) method?

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("some text");    

        int pos = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (matcher.find(pos))
        {
            int start = matcher.start();
            int end = matcher.end();
            pos = end;
            System.out.format("%d", i++);
        }
```

Comment: Because of `end=start` if your matching string is empty and hence has length=0. Hence you never change the position. You might want to do something with you `i` :-).

Comment: ty. I expose the regexp to the user. The user can edit regex in textarea and run it against another textarea's text. The code relies on find(int) to highlight the found strings. The problem here is that the loop occurs only on runtime when "" string is given by the user and this problem found only on testing. Do you know any other regexp's that could break this code?

Comment: Yep, ?, *, .{0,42} and so on. I would test the regex first against an empty String or increase the position manually by at least 1, e.g. in your code `pos = Math.max(pos+1, end);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the pattern is an empty string, the `pos` value will always be zero. In this case, you don't need to pass the `pos` argument to `find`. Just call the no-arg `find`. Note that the two method overloads behave differently. For `find(index)`:

> **Resets this matcher** and then attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern, starting at the specified index.

For the no-arg `find()`:

> Attempts to find the **next subsequence** of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
>
> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, **if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match**.